# SurfaceTrimmer for pcl::Poisson

Tags: c++, pcl

Im trying to adapt `SurfaceTrimmer` from [M.Kazdan's Poisson Recon](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version5.71/) to PCL.
Is there way to estimate depth values of the iso-surface vertices in pcl::Poisson like in the original work(`--density` in `PoissonRecon`)?